# Using Python's json.loads with JSON containing regex value, breaks?

Tags: python, json, regex

**TL,DR;** How can JSON containing a regex with escaped backslahes, be loaded using [Python's JSON decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

**Detail;** The regular expression `\\[0-9]\\` will match (for example):

```
\2\
```

The same regular expression could be encoded as a JSON value:

```
{
  "pattern": "\\[0-9]\\"
}
```

And in turn, the JSON value could be encoded as a string in Python (note the single quotes):

```
'{"pattern": "\\[0-9]\\"}'
```

When loading the JSON in Python, a [JSONDecodeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is raised:

```
import json
json.loads('{"pattern": "\\[0-9]\\"}')
```

The problem is caused by the regular expression escaping the blackslashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 14 (char 13)
>>> json.loads('{"pattern": "\\[0-9]\\"}')
```

This surprised me since each step seems reasonable (i.e. valid regex, valid JSON, and valid Python).

How can JSON containing a regex with escaped backslahes, be loaded using [Python's JSON decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: `json.loads(r'{"pattern": "\\[0-9]\\"}')`

Comment: What's your *actual* JSON? Your string literal isn't right but whatever you're loading ought to be.

Comment: What is the regex error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that Python is first escaping the input to `loads` as a string literal, making it `'{"pattern": "\[0-9]\"}'` (double backslash -> single backslash). Then, `loads` now attempts to escape `\[`, which is invalid. To fix, escape the backslashes again. However, it's easier and more practical to specify it as a raw string:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"pattern": "\\[0-9]\\"}')
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 14 (char 13)
>>> json.loads(r'{"pattern": "\\[0-9]\\"}')
{'pattern': '\\[0-9]\\'} # No error
```

Note that this problem won't apply if loading from a file.

`test.json`:

```
{"pattern": "\\[0-9]\\"}
```

Python:

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as infile:
    json.load(infile) # no problem
```

Basically, the problem arises with the fact that you're passing in a string *literal*, but ironically, your string *literal* isn't being taken *literally*.

Comment: And how would this be done without using the raw syntax ?

Comment: @sln: Escape the backslashes again: `'{"pattern": "\\\\[0-9]\\\\"}'`

Comment: @sln I mean, you could do `'{"pattern": "\\\\[0-9]\\\\"}'`, but especially if you're getting the json string from an outside source, the raw syntax is better.

Comment: So in python single quoted string is the same as a double quoted one ? where `'\n'` is a carriage return ?

Comment: @sln Yep. The only real difference is with single quoted strings, you need to escape single but not double quotes, and with double quotes, you need to escape double but not single quotes.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Thanks for the answer, but how can a string be specified as a raw string if it's *not* a string literal, but a variable?

Comment: @Jack Unfortunately, if it's a variable, the backslashes will have already been escaped (i.e. it's stored as one backslash, not two). Where are you getting this JSON from? The only possible way for a variable to have its backslashes escaped is if you're declaring it as a string literal, as Python will only escape string literals. I added an example to my answer where reading from a file is no problem, if that helps.

Comment: Why is it that we have the double backslash *before* the left bracket but *after* the right bracket?

Comment: @tony_tiger I don't really understand your question, it's just OP's regex pattern.

Comment: @Tomothy32 - thanks for the example. Regarding your answer, you wrote _Python is first escaping the input to loads as a string literal, making it '{"pattern": "\[0-9]\"}' (double backslash -> single backslash)_.  Surely, if a string is escaped, a backslash would be **added**, rather than removed? See https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: @Jack I should have worded that better, I meant that Python processes escape sequences in the string literal. For example, replacing `\n` with newline, `\t` with tab, etc.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Right, so _processing_ in this context means removing the escape character, to yield the actual meaning of the special character. The escape sequence \\ would remove the first \ leaving only the special character \.The special character is then passed into `json.loads`.

Comment: @Jack Yeah, that's essentially it.

Comment: @Jack - If you think that a file contains the raw escape character you can always replace all `(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*\\)(?!\\)` with `\\$1`

Answer (score 0):

The `r` means that the string is to be treated as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be ignored:

```
json.loads(r'{"pattern": "\\[0-9]\\"}')
```